# SUM/IF Statement with Text input and a Numeric Sum output in Excel

Tags: excel

Ok, I am having trouble with this equation.  I have (4) rows for text entries that have a numeric association depending on what you input.  The equation I have does not SUM all four rows.  With each text input of `"I"=100`,`"P"=86`,`"N"=63` with a sum dependant on what was input.

```
=SUM(IF(A4:D4="I",100)+IF(A4:D4="P",86)+IF(A4:D4="N",63,0))
```

I should have the number `400` in `E4` with `"I"` entered in `A4:D4`, or `344` in `E4` with `"P"` entered in `A4:D4`.

Thank you for any help you can give.

KC

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with an "Array" Formula like so

```
=SUM((A1:D1="I")*100,(A1:D1="P")*86,(A1:D1="N")*63)
```

You have to enter this with Ctrl-Shift and Enter, and it will be enclosed in curly brackets.

Look up "Array Formulas" for details, they're a pain to get your head around but will save you a lot of extra columns.

Can take a while to calculate on a large sheet mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert values in adjacent cells: (I will transpose the data for simplicity of formatting)

```
   |  A  |  B  |
1  |  I  | =IF(A1="I";100;IF(A1="P";86;IF(A1="N";63;0)))
2  |  I  | =IF(A1="I";100;IF(A1="P";86;IF(A1="N";63;0)))
3  |  I  | =IF(A1="I";100;IF(A1="P";86;IF(A1="N";63;0)))
4  |  I  | =IF(A1="I";100;IF(A1="P";86;IF(A1="N";63;0)))
```

Then in `E4` you have : `SUM(A1:A4)`